# Is it possible to automate Oracle Forms through Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, oracleforms

Can anyone share your views whether we can automate Oracle Forms through Selenium?
One of the forms doesn't contain any locators (web elements) and only contains JavaScript functions. Alternatively, is it possible to call JS through Selenium?

Please suggest me best way or correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I can't find a demo, could you please share one?

Comment: I can see the question is quite older, Is it still not possible to automate oracle forms using selenium latest versions?

Comment: @AppuMistri Not with Selenium but other testing software can do it. One of them is TestComplete from SmartBear. I'm not related to them but just tried their trail version. It offers record and playback and scripting features.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know, for what I know it should be impossible at this moment with Selenium.

Oracle web forms run in a java applet object inside html (they are just one object in the DOM) so Javascript doesn't know any of the internal forms objects, and hence, can't record the operations or manipulate the form.

I'm also sorry it doesn't as we do a lot of development with Oracle Forms.

Best regards.